# Web Platform Installer Automatic Updates

Tags: iis

Does the web platform installer support automatic updates? Assuming I configured nothing, would the web platform installer:

1: Check for automatic updates.

2: Install them automatically and without my permission.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?